# OpenCV 3d reconstruction: compilation error ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: opencv, 3d

I am trying to compile a sample code for 3d reconstruction with OpenCV and I am getting the following error (1)

Source code you can find here: https://sites.google.com/site/3drecon124/

Error List

(1) error C2668: 'sqrt' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

(2) IntelliSense: more than one instance of overloaded function "sqrt" matches the argument list

(3) IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that the compiler cannot choose appropriate overloading `sqrt` function.

Please try to specify type of operand explicitly:

```
sqrt(double(T_pts[i].x*T_pts[i].x + T_pts[i].y*T_pts[i].y));
...
float scale=sqrt(2.0)/meandist.val[0];
```

instead of:

```
dist[i]=sqrt(T_pts[i].x*T_pts[i].x+T_pts[i].y*T_pts[i].y); // It won't hurt to specify operand type

float scale=sqrt(2)/meandist.val[0]; // here '2' has int type
```